# How do I set the Oscillator module in a DSPIC33E?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

So ive got a DSPIC33EP128GM604 PIC, and Im trying to set the internal fast RC oscillator as the clock source. Ive read the datasheet and the application note both of which tell me to use the macro:
 `_FOSCSEL( OPT1_ON & OPT2_OFF & OPT3_PLL )`

However, whenever I set the relevant bits, i get the following error during compile time:

> computed address for section __FOSCSEL extends beyond MEMORY region FOSCSEL

Ive googled this problem, and searched the Microchip forms but oddly i can find no similar problems and solutions. Ive selected the mentioned PIC in the project and have set up all the relevant header files (i used the DSPIC33E template provided by MPLABX).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is a problem with a linker file or include file.  In any case, the syntax you are trying to use doesn't allow for good commenting on what exactly each of the settings means, and gives no indication at all of what other options might have been that you didn't chose.

I always set the config bits in assembler source, and document each bit.  Below is a section from one of my current projects using the 33EP512GM604, which is almost the same chip.  This section is always re-written for each project, and would have to be carefully inspected if the project was moved to a different part.  I'm therefore not that bothered by the fixed starting location, although that wasn't my first choice.  I vaguely remember that I ran into some linker problem using the pre-defined directives, so set the address and started writing program memory words myself.  Either way, the point is how each bit is carefully documented, what was chosen, and some idea of what other choices might have been.

```
;*******************************************************************************
;
;   Static processor configuration settings.
;
.section .configbits, code, address(0x557EC)

         .pword  0xFFFFFF    ;reserved
         .pword  0xFFFFFF    ;reserved

         .pword  0b111111111111111111001111 ;FICD
                 ; 1111111111111111-------- unused, all 1s makes NOP instruction
                 ; ----------------1------- reserved, must be set to 1
                 ; -----------------1------ unused
                 ; ------------------0----- disable JTAG
                 ; -------------------0---- reserved, must be set to 0
                 ; --------------------1--- reserved, must be set to 1
                 ; ---------------------1-- unused
                 ; ----------------------11 ICD interface uses PGEC1/PGED1

         .pword  0b111111111111111100111111 ;FPOR
                 ; 1111111111111111-------- unused, all 1s makes NOP instruction
                 ; ----------------00------ WDT window is 75% of period
                 ; ------------------1----- IIC2 uses SDA2/SCL2 pins
                 ; -------------------1---- IIC1 users SDA1/SCL1 pins
                 ; --------------------1--- enable brownout reset
                 ; ---------------------111 unused

         .pword  0b111111111111111101111111 ;FWDT
                 ; 1111111111111111-------- unused, all 1s makes NOP instruction
                 ; ----------------0------- WDT not always enabled
                 ; -----------------1------ WDT in non-window mode
                 ; ------------------1----- enable PLL lock
                 ; -------------------1---- WDT prescalser 128, not 32
                 ; --------------------1111 WDT postscaler to max of 32768

         .pword  0b111111111111111101011110 ;FOSC
                 ; 1111111111111111-------- unused, all 1s makes NOP instruction
                 ; ----------------01------ clock switching enabled, failsafe clk disabled
                 ; ------------------0----- allow multiple PPS changes
                 ; -------------------11--- unused
                 ; ---------------------1-- not used with external crystal oscillator
                 ; ----------------------10 primary oscillator mode is HS

         .pword  0b111111111111111100111010 ;FOSCSEL
                 ; 1111111111111111-------- unused, all 1s makes NOP instruction
                 ; ----------------0------- start with selected osc mode, not FRC
                 ; -----------------0------ don't require key sequence for PWM registers
                 ; ------------------111--- unused
                 ; ---------------------010 start with primary osc, not PLL

         .pword  0b111111111111111111111111 ;FGS
                 ; 1111111111111111-------- unused, all 1s makes NOP instruction
                 ; ----------------111111-- unused
                 ; ----------------------1- disable user memory code protection
                 ; -----------------------1 disable user memory write protection

         .pword  0xFFFFFF    ;reserved
         .pword  0xFFFFFF    ;reserved
```

Comment: I will try to do it the way you did. However, is this error implying that the register location im trying to write to with that macro doesnt exist on the PIC? if that is the case, i have confirmed with the header file for the PIC provided by XC16 and the datasheet, and the address of the register seems fine to me. Odd.

Comment: @Adil: Obviously the config values exist, else the chip couldn't be configured.  There may be a typo in the linker file or some include file.  It happens.  As I said, I vaguely remember running into some problem, which is why I reverted to the hard coded address of the start of the config bits.  Remember on this part the config bits you write in the code are kept in program memory, then copied to the actual volatile config registers by the hardware as part of the reset sequence.

Comment: I had a similar bug earlier this year, and a Microchip FAE confirmed it was a bug in the XC16 compiler itself -- a regression that had snuck in. Hopefully it's a typo in a linker file and doesn't require Microchip intervention, but you can post on their forums as well.

Comment: If your FAE knows about the bug, I'm sure this has been passed to Calum by now, and it will be fixed in a future XC16 release.